# How to over ride node end of life error without updating node?

Tags: node.js, npm, version, nvm

So, couple of years ago I wrote some ionic code using node v8.11.2. Today I made some very minute changes for some calculation in my code.

The issue which I run into is

```
$ ionic
ERR: Your Node.js version is v8.11.2. Node.js 8 reached end-of-life on 2019-12-31 and is no longer supported. Please update to the latest Node LTS version.
```

I really don't want to update the node as I am sure something else might break and earlier the same code had successfully complied.

Is there any way to tell node to not check for the end of life and just continue with the build with whatever you have?

Comment: did you manage to find solutions to this @Chetan

Comment: @GautamChibde , the culprit is ionic and not node. The ionic requires the new node and hence I changes the node version to solve this